# How to wait in a loop when playing a viewlist with naudio?

Tags: vb.net, listview, naudio, playlist

I am kinda new in vb.net 
So I am trying to play some mp3 from a listview using naudio but I cannot find the way to wait till the next song start, without losing focus of the stop and pause buttons.
Using thread.sleep loses the ability to stop the list.
Using doevents() keep focus but doesnt really works.

Any ideas?

```
If WaveOut.PlaybackState <> PlaybackState.Paused Then
                For i = 0 To MusicList.Items.Count - 1
                    Dim audio As AudioFileReader = New AudioFileReader(MusicList.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text)
                    Dim player As IWavePlayer = New WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback)
                    player.Init(audio)
                    player.Play()
                    While player.PlaybackState = PlaybackState.Playing
                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
                    End While
                    player.Stop()
                    player.Dispose()
                    audio.Dispose()
                    player = Nothing
                    audio = Nothing
                Next
End If
```

Comment: I don't use NAudio so I'm not 100% sure but I just spent 30 seconds doing some searching and it appears to me that what you need to do is not wait.  Call `Play` and that should be the ned of that method.  If you handle the `PlaybackStopped` event then your event handler will be executed when what you're playing finishes.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Eventually I used the `PlaybackStopped` event. After some hours of infinite loops I understand that I had to `RemoveHandler` it too at the end of the playlist in order to rewind list to the beginning. So, problem solved. Thank you.